# I need to declare private, public and static variables in java, is there any specific order to follow in declaration of these variables?

Tags: java

I need to declare private, public and static variables in java, is there any specific order to follow in declaration of these variables

```
public class Test  
{ 

    private String name;  
    public String address;  
    private static final String DR_NO = "1-44-54/4";  

}
```

Is there any specification to declare these variables?

Comment: Personally, I like `static final` variables first, but that's more about habit then anything else.  Simply try and remain consistent.

Comment: Are you asking what's best practice or what the language requires? For the latter, you can declare them in whatever order you like and it'll still compile. For best practice, just be consistent and clear.

Comment: Its a matter of preference.. I agree with @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can declare fields in whichever order you want. Same for methods, constructors, and inner classes.

The only thing to watch out for is that: static fields will be initialized before instance fields (of course), but static fields and instance fields will be initialized in the order you declared them.

So if you had this:

```
class A {
    static String b = "hello ";
    static String a = b + " world";
    static void print() {System.out.println(a);}
}
```

then calling `print` prints "hello world", but if you had this:

```
class A {
    static String a = b + " world";
    static String b = "hello ";
    static void print() {System.out.println(a);}
}
```

then it would print "null world", as `b` contained the value `null` when `a` was initialized.